# How to insert new data to existing coredata in swift3

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

**I am trying to insert new data to existed core data .But the new data is repeating . what is the problem with my code ?**

```
func getContext(){

        let container: NSPersistentContainer? = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.persistentContainer

        let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate

        if let context = container?.viewContext{

        let request = NSFetchRequest<Mydata>(entityName: "Mydata")
        do {
            let searchResults = try context.fetch(request)

            let person1 = searchResults[0]

           if person1.value(forKey: "iD") as! String != self.myiddddddd {

           let person = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Mydata",


            person.setValue(nameFunc, forKey: "name")

            person.setValue(imageArray, forKeyPath: "profimg")
            person.setValue(postImageArray, forKeyPath: "mid_img")

            person.setValue(myUId, forKey: "iD")

            do{

              try (context.save())
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in

                                      self.myTable.reloadData()
                                   })

            }
            catch
            {
                print(error)
            }
            catch {

            }
            }


        } catch {
            print("Error with request: \(error)")
        }

        }

        }
```

"myiddddddd" is the newdata(post id ) from the json .Please help

Comment: Is that code even compiling ?? Looks like you missing few '}' ???

Comment: Can't read this, please reformat the code. Are your xcdatamodel and your model configured properly?

Comment: previously i did like  - person1.setValue(imageArray, forKeyPath: "profimg")  .But it replaces the first object . so now i am trying to insert data . But it repeating the same data

Comment: actually i am saving json data to the coredata , and showing it on the table view. it will fetch data on background  and will update the coredata

Comment: fetch is returning array of Person objects and your if checks only first object while it should loop on every object